# Css floating two elements inside a jquery ui themed widget

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Testing PasteHTML.com</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="http://optdev.shellprompt.net/css/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="notification" id="notification-message">
            <div class="ui-widget">
                <div style="padding: 0 .7em;" class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all"> 
                    <span style="float: right;cursor:pointer" onclick="$x_Remove('notification-message')" class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
                    <div id="message" style="float:left">Invalid Login Credentials</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Both the Message and "X" apear outside of their parent div. How do I place them inside their parent?

Here is a demo http://pastehtml.com/view/bngl4k1th.html and I would like it to look like JQuery UI Theme http://tinyurl.com/dbqg2t Alert message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just been working through the jQuery UI Theme and I was missing the ui-helper-clearfix class once I added that it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add `overflow:hidden` to the parent tag or a new div with the `clear:both` property, before ending the parent tag.